# NestJS - Export Custom Factory Provider (useFactory)

Tags: nestjs

I have created a custom provider in one of my modules.
I need to export that custom provider to make it available in other modules and I'm having trouble doing so. I do not know what to put in the exports array.
Below is my custom provider.

```js
    @Module({
      imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([TypeOrmUser])],
      providers: [
        UserMapper,
        UserService,
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(TypeOrmUser),
          inject: [getDataSourceToken()],
          useFactory(dataSource: DataSource) {
            return dataSource.getRepository(TypeOrmUser).extend(userRepositoryImpl);
          },
        },
      ],
      exports: [UserService, 'what to put here to export custom user repository?'],
    })
    export class UsersModule {}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To export a custom provider, all that is needed to be added to the `exports` array is the provider's injection token.

In this case, that's `getRepositoryToken(TypeOrmUser)`

Answer (score 1):

You can export it either with *token* name, or with the whole provider *object*. In your case it would be something like this:

```ts
exports: [UserService, getRepositoryToken(TypeOrmUser)],
```

or:

```ts
const customProvider = {
  provide: getRepositoryToken(TypeOrmUser),
    inject: [getDataSourceToken()],
    useFactory(dataSource: DataSource) {
      return dataSource.getRepository(TypeOrmUser).extend(userRepositoryImpl);
  },
};

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([TypeOrmUser])],
  providers: [
    UserMapper,
    UserService,
    customProvider,
  ],
  exports: [UserService, customProvider],
})
```